# how get need array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i do this on php and can't combine right array

```
array (
  0 => 'uttt',
)
```

must add to array

```
  0 => '534',
  1 => 'DT 8060',
  2 => '6y45y',
  **4 => 'uttt',**
```

and all arrays must do also
i not know how much will array
this do in foreach
please people help me

```html
array (
  0 => 'uttt',
)
array (
  0 => '534',
  1 => 'DT 8060',
  2 => '6y45y',
)
array (
  0 => '639',
  1 => 'DP 42',
  2 => '88765',
)
array (
  0 => '1470',
  1 => '95126F',
  2 => 'yt44y5',
)
array (
  0 => '1473',
  1 => '95406F',
  2 => 'yyynb rt',
)
array (
  0 => 'ytree',
)
array (
  0 => '3338',
  1 => 'DI 113 ШК',
  2 => 'rdde',
)
array (
  0 => '1476',
  1 => '96010',
  2 => 'ouuhh',
)
array (
  0 => 'nnggg',
)
array (
  0 => '2169',
  1 => 'DT 88263-2',
  2 => 'rhrd',
)
array (
  0 => '2657',
  1 => 'DP 10-1',
  2 => 'klii',
)
array (
  0 => 'ergerg',
)
array (
  0 => '544',
  1 => '96205',
  2 => 'njnj sgsg',
)
```

me need get such array

```html
    array (
      0 => '534',
      1 => 'DT 8060',
      2 => '6y45y',
      3 => 'uttt',
    )
    array (
      0 => '639',
      1 => 'DP 42',
      2 => '88765',
       3 => 'uttt',
    )
    array (
      0 => '1470',
      1 => '95126F',
      2 => 'yt44y5',
      3 => 'uttt',
    )
    array (
      0 => '1473',
      1 => '95406F',
      2 => 'yyynb rt',
      3 => 'uttt',
    )
    array (
      0 => '3338',
      1 => 'DI 113 ШК',
      2 => 'rdde',
      3 => 'ytree',
    )
    array (
      0 => '1476',
      1 => '96010',
      2 => 'ouuhh',
      3 => 'ytree',
    )
    array (
      0 => '2169',
      1 => 'DT 88263-2',
      2 => 'rhrd',
      3 => 'nnggg',
    )
    array (
      0 => '2657',
      1 => 'DP 10-1',
      2 => 'klii',
      3 => 'nnggg',
    )
    array (
      0 => '544',
      1 => '96205',
      2 => 'njnj sgsg',
      0 => 'ergerg',
    )
```

how do this? i'am not know

Comment: Tried [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) or [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)? Tried _anything_ at all? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Put all the `arrays` into 1 `array`. Then `loop` over it. Check if it has only 1 entry. If yes, `push` this to all the next `arrays`. Until a new 1 entry comes. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = [];
$arrayToMerge = [];
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    if (count($array) == 1) {
        $arrayToMerge = $array;
    }
    else {
        $result[] = array_push($array, $arrayToMerge);
    }
}
return $result;
```

Try this

Comment: so return array null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(0 => 'uttt');
array_unshift($arr1, '534', 'DT 8060', '6y45y');
```

If you print your `$arr1` the result would be like this:

```
array (
  0 => '534',
  1 => 'DT 8060',
  2 => '6y45y',
  3 => 'uttt'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) Documentation

**NOTE**: only problem with `array_merge` is that if `$aone` and `atwo` are associative array and if both having same key then second array key will be replaced

```
<?php
    $aone = array (  0 => 'uttt');
    $atwo = array( 0 => '534',  1 => 'DT 8060',  2 => '6y45y');

    //your solution
    $result_array = array_merge($atwo,$aone);

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($aone);
        print_r($atwo);
        print_r($result_array);
    echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

[image]

================================================================================

Not so good by atleast have something

Solution Two for multiple array

create array variable using serial name like a1,a2,a3 so on and

same above concept used for $result_array like $result_array1,2,3 so on

then use them in for loop

Use below code i hope this will help

if any question ask

```
<?php
    $a1 = array (  0 => 'uttt');
    $a2 = array( 0 => '534',  1 => 'DT 8060',  2 => '6y45y');

    $a3 = array (
              0 => '534',
              1 => 'DT 8060',
              2 => '6y45y',
            );
    $a4 =array (
      0 => '639',
      1 => 'DP 42',
      2 => '88765',
    );

    $a5=array (
      0 => '1470',
      1 => '95126F',
      2 => 'yt44y5',
    );


    //start loop from 2 becaues 1 is going to be appended
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        //second array is set to a1  becasue you want to add only that array
        //created new result_array for each mearge result_array1,result_array2 so on
        ${'result_array'.$i} = array_merge(${'a'.($i+1)}, $a1 );
    }


    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){

        echo '<pre>';
            print_r(${'result_array'.$i});
        echo '</pre>';
    }




 ?>
```

**Output of new solution**

[image]

Comment: Joshi how this do in cicle all arrays 
together i not know how divide them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$finalArr = [];
foreach($currentArra as $arr):

    if(count($arr) == 1){
        $arrToBeMerge=[];
        $arrToBeMerge = $arr;
    }

    if(!empty($arrToBeMerge) && count($arr)>1){
        $result = array_merge($arr , $arrToBeMerge);
        array_push($finalArr, $result);
    }

endforeach;
echo '<pre>';print_r($finalArr);
```